# Silverlight Design Resources for the Inept

Tags: silverlight

I'm steadily progressing on Silverlight from a programming standpoint.  I believe I'm to the point where I want my application to look decent to begin demo'ing.  Doesn't have to look awesome, but not like a 2 year old did it (although a 2 year old might be a step above my current design skills).  With HTML, you could typically find some designs, credit the author and off you go with a reasonably decent looking web application.  I guess Silverlight is too young to have these sorts of resources, or perhaps I'm just having trouble locating them.

Are there any starting points that a lowly developer like me can mold into my application?  I don't need anything fancy, just something clean and visually appealing.  If the answer is 'sorry chump, ya gotta pay a pro', I can live with that.  But wanted to see if there were other avenues I hadn't considered to create a decent looking proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the free icons at famfam:
http://famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/

The silk ones especially are really slick and have helped me a lot in the past.
Good looking icons and buttons go a long way towards polishing the look of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I already have an icon library.  I was looking for some designs that I could use as a springboard.  Maybe something similar to http://www.oswd.org/ but for Silverlight.